# Installing LuaJIT LuaRocks Torch7 on Windows 10 with VS2013 x64 or VS2017 x64 (fail at Torch7)

Tags: windows, lua, torch, luajit, luarocks

I spent the past 3 days struggling to have Lua with Torch installed on my new Windows 10 laptop. Reading many stack overflow posts on the subject I came to think my best option was to follow very closely Siavash Gorji 's instructions - see: https://libraries.io/github/SiavashGorji/LuaJIT-Luarocks-Torch7.

LuaJIT and LuaRocks installed fine, but "luarocks install torch" command fails (fails when building torch7 using either VS2013 x64 or VS2017 x64).

First of, even if both LuaJIT and LuaRocks successfully build and run, here is what the first cmake did output:

```
(no source code here, just compiler outputs)

D:\luainstall-64\build>cmake .. -G "NMake Makefiles" -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=%LuaJIT-Luarocks-Torch7_ROOT%\install
-- The C compiler identification is MSVC 18.0.40629.0
-- The CXX compiler identification is MSVC 18.0.40629.0
-- Check for working C compiler: D:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0/VC/bin/amd64/cl.exe
-- Check for working C compiler: D:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0/VC/bin/amd64/cl.exe -- works
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info - done
-- Detecting C compile features
-- Detecting C compile features - done
-- Check for working CXX compiler: D:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0/VC/bin/amd64/cl.exe
-- Check for working CXX compiler: D:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0/VC/bin/amd64/cl.exe -- works
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info - done
-- Detecting CXX compile features
-- Detecting CXX compile features - done
-- The ASM compiler identification is MSVC
-- Found assembler: D:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0/VC/bin/amd64/cl.exe
-- Looking for sys/types.h
-- Looking for sys/types.h - found
-- Looking for stdint.h
-- Looking for stdint.h - found
-- Looking for stddef.h
-- Looking for stddef.h - found
-- Check size of void*
-- Check size of void* - done
-- Looking for sin in m
-- Looking for sin in m - not found
-- Looking for pthread.h
-- Looking for pthread.h - not found
-- Found Threads: TRUE
-- Performing Test LJ_TARGET_X64
-- Performing Test LJ_TARGET_X64 - Success
-- LuaJIT Target: x64
-- LuaJIT target x64
-- Performing Test LJ_ARCH_BITS_64
-- Performing Test LJ_ARCH_BITS_64 - Success
-- Performing Test LJ_HASJIT_1
-- Performing Test LJ_HASJIT_1 - Success
-- Performing Test LJ_HASFFI_1
-- Performing Test LJ_HASFFI_1 - Success
-- Performing Test LJ_DUALNUM_1
-- Performing Test LJ_DUALNUM_1 - Failed
-- Performing Test LJ_ARCH_HASFPU_1
-- Performing Test LJ_ARCH_HASFPU_1 - Success
-- Performing Test LJ_ABI_SOFTFP_1
-- Performing Test LJ_ABI_SOFTFP_1 - Failed
-- Looking for sin in m
-- Looking for sin in m - not found
-- Configuring done
-- Generating done
-- Build files have been written to: D:/luainstall-64/build



And last, when Torch7 build problem occurs, I have this (partial) output (focusing on things that may cause of the problem):

D:\luainstall-64\build>luarocks install torch

D:\luainstall-64\build>rem=rem --[[
Installing https://raw.githubusercontent.com/torch/rocks/master/torch-scm-1.rockspec...
Using https://raw.githubusercontent.com/torch/rocks/master/torch-scm-1.rockspec... switching to 'build' mode
Cloning into 'torch7'...
remote: Enumerating objects: 181, done.
remote: Counting objects: 100% (181/181), done.
remote: Compressing objects: 100% (174/174), done.
Receiving objects: 100% (181/181), 335.48 KiB | 1.00 MiB/s, done.ceiving objects:  98% (178/181)

Resolving deltas: 100% (8/8), done.
cmake -E make_directory build && cd build && cmake .. -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release -DLUA=D:/luainstall-64/install/./luajit -DLUALIB=libluajit.lib -DLUA_BINDIR="D:/luainstall-64/install/." -DLUA_INCDIR="D:/luainstall-64/install/include" -DLUA_LIBDIR="D:/luainstall-64/install/." -DLUADIR="D:/luainstall-64/install/luarocks/torch/scm-1/lua" -DLIBDIR="D:/luainstall-64/install/luarocks/torch/scm-1/lib" -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX="D:/luainstall-64/install/luarocks/torch/scm-1" && nmake


D:\Users\docte\AppData\Local\Temp\luarocks_torch-scm-1-1820\torch7>if -E == -E (cmake.exe  -E make_directory build  )  else (cmake.exe -G "NMake Makefiles"  -DWIN32=1  -E make_directory build )

D:\Users\docte\AppData\Local\Temp\luarocks_torch-scm-1-1820\torch7\build>if .. == -E (cmake.exe  .. -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release -DLUA=D:/luainstall-64/install/./luajit -DLUALIB=libluajit.lib -DLUA_BINDIR="D:/luainstall-64/install/." -DLUA_INCDIR="D:/luainstall-64/install/include" -DLUA_LIBDIR="D:/luainstall-64/install/." -DLUADIR="D:/luainstall-64/install/luarocks/torch/scm-1/lua" -DLIBDIR="D:/luainstall-64/install/luarocks/torch/scm-1/lib" -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX="D:/luainstall-64/install/luarocks/torch/scm-1"  )  else (cmake.exe -G "NMake Makefiles"  -DWIN32=1  .. -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release -DLUA=D:/luainstall-64/install/./luajit -DLUALIB=libluajit.lib -DLUA_BINDIR="D:/luainstall-64/install/." -DLUA_INCDIR="D:/luainstall-64/install/include" -DLUA_LIBDIR="D:/luainstall-64/install/." -DLUADIR="D:/luainstall-64/install/luarocks/torch/scm-1/lua" -DLIBDIR="D:/luainstall-64/install/luarocks/torch/scm-1/lib" -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX="D:/luainstall-64/install/luarocks/torch/scm-1" )
-- The C compiler identification is MSVC 18.0.40629.0
-- The CXX compiler identification is MSVC 18.0.40629.0
-- Check for working C compiler: D:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0/VC/bin/amd64/cl.exe
-- Check for working C compiler: D:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0/VC/bin/amd64/cl.exe -- works
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info - done
-- Detecting C compile features
-- Detecting C compile features - done
-- Check for working CXX compiler: D:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0/VC/bin/amd64/cl.exe
-- Check for working CXX compiler: D:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0/VC/bin/amd64/cl.exe -- works
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info - done
-- Detecting CXX compile features
-- Detecting CXX compile features - done
-- Found OpenMP_C: -openmp (found version "2.0")
-- Found OpenMP_CXX: -openmp (found version "2.0")
-- Found OpenMP: TRUE (found version "2.0")
-- Compiling with OpenMP support
CMake Deprecation Warning at lib/TH/CMakeLists.txt:5 (CMAKE_POLICY):
  The OLD behavior for policy CMP0026 will be removed from a future version
  of CMake.

  The cmake-policies(7) manual explains that the OLD behaviors of all
  policies are deprecated and that a policy should be set to OLD only under
  specific short-term circumstances.  Projects should be ported to the NEW
  behavior and not rely on setting a policy to OLD.


-- Compiling with OpenMP support
-- Could not find hardware support for NEON on this machine.
-- No OMAP3 processor on this machine.
-- No OMAP4 processor on this machine.
-- Looking for cpuid.h
-- Looking for cpuid.h - not found
-- Performing Test NO_GCC_EBX_FPIC_BUG
-- Performing Test NO_GCC_EBX_FPIC_BUG - Failed
-- Performing Test C_HAS_SSE1_1
-- Performing Test C_HAS_SSE1_1 - Success
-- Performing Test C_HAS_SSE2_1
-- Performing Test C_HAS_SSE2_1 - Success
-- Performing Test C_HAS_SSE3_1
-- Performing Test C_HAS_SSE3_1 - Success
-- Performing Test C_HAS_SSE4_1_1
-- Performing Test C_HAS_SSE4_1_1 - Success
-- Performing Test C_HAS_SSE4_2_1
-- Performing Test C_HAS_SSE4_2_1 - Success
-- Performing Test C_HAS_AVX_1
-- Performing Test C_HAS_AVX_1 - Success
-- Performing Test C_HAS_AVX2_1
-- Performing Test C_HAS_AVX2_1 - Success
-- Performing Test CXX_HAS_SSE1_1
-- Performing Test CXX_HAS_SSE1_1 - Success
-- Performing Test CXX_HAS_SSE2_1
-- Performing Test CXX_HAS_SSE2_1 - Success
-- Performing Test CXX_HAS_SSE3_1
-- Performing Test CXX_HAS_SSE3_1 - Success
-- Performing Test CXX_HAS_SSE4_1_1
-- Performing Test CXX_HAS_SSE4_1_1 - Success
-- Performing Test CXX_HAS_SSE4_2_1
-- Performing Test CXX_HAS_SSE4_2_1 - Success
-- Performing Test CXX_HAS_AVX_1
-- Performing Test CXX_HAS_AVX_1 - Success
-- Performing Test CXX_HAS_AVX2_1
-- Performing Test CXX_HAS_AVX2_1 - Success
-- SSE2 Found
-- SSE3 Found
-- AVX Found
-- AVX2 Found
-- Performing Test HAS_C11_ATOMICS
-- Performing Test HAS_C11_ATOMICS - Failed
-- Performing Test HAS_MSC_ATOMICS
-- Performing Test HAS_MSC_ATOMICS - Success
-- Performing Test HAS_GCC_ATOMICS
-- Performing Test HAS_GCC_ATOMICS - Failed
-- TH_SO_VERSION: 0
-- Atomics: using MSVC intrinsics
-- Looking for sys/types.h
-- Looking for sys/types.h - found
-- Looking for stdint.h
-- Looking for stdint.h - found
-- Looking for stddef.h
-- Looking for stddef.h - found
-- Check size of void*
-- Check size of void* - done
-- Checking for [mkl_intel_lp64 - mkl_intel_thread - mkl_core - libiomp5md - pthread]
--   Library mkl_intel_lp64: not found
-- Checking for [mkl_intel - mkl_intel_thread - mkl_core - libiomp5md - pthread]
--   Library mkl_intel: not found
-- Checking for [mkl_intel_lp64 - mkl_intel_thread - mkl_core - pthread]
--   Library mkl_intel_lp64: not found
-- Checking for [mkl_intel - mkl_intel_thread - mkl_core - pthread]
--   Library mkl_intel: not found
-- Checking for [mkl_intel_lp64 - mkl_sequential - mkl_core]
--   Library mkl_intel_lp64: not found
-- Checking for [mkl_intel - mkl_sequential - mkl_core]
--   Library mkl_intel: not found
-- Checking for [mkl_intel_lp64 - mkl_sequential - mkl_core]
--   Library mkl_intel_lp64: not found
-- Checking for [mkl_intel - mkl_sequential - mkl_core]
--   Library mkl_intel: not found
-- Checking for [mkl_intel_lp64 - mkl_intel_thread - mkl_core - libiomp5md - pthread]
--   Library mkl_intel_lp64: not found
-- Checking for [mkl_intel - mkl_intel_thread - mkl_core - libiomp5md - pthread]
--   Library mkl_intel: not found
-- Checking for [mkl_intel_lp64 - mkl_intel_thread - mkl_core - pthread]
--   Library mkl_intel_lp64: not found
-- Checking for [mkl_intel - mkl_intel_thread - mkl_core - pthread]
--   Library mkl_intel: not found
-- Checking for [mkl - guide - pthread - m]
--   Library mkl: not found
-- MKL library not found
-- Checking for [openblas]
--   Library openblas: BLAS_openblas_LIBRARY-NOTFOUND
-- Checking for [openblas - pthread]
--   Library openblas: BLAS_openblas_LIBRARY-NOTFOUND
-- Checking for [libopenblas]
--   Library libopenblas: BLAS_libopenblas_LIBRARY-NOTFOUND
-- Checking for [goto2 - gfortran]
--   Library goto2: BLAS_goto2_LIBRARY-NOTFOUND
-- Checking for [goto2 - gfortran - pthread]
--   Library goto2: BLAS_goto2_LIBRARY-NOTFOUND
-- Checking for [acml - gfortran]
--   Library acml: BLAS_acml_LIBRARY-NOTFOUND
-- Checking for [Accelerate]
--   Library Accelerate: BLAS_Accelerate_LIBRARY-NOTFOUND
-- Checking for [vecLib]
--   Library vecLib: BLAS_vecLib_LIBRARY-NOTFOUND
-- Checking for [ptf77blas - atlas - gfortran]
--   Library ptf77blas: BLAS_ptf77blas_LIBRARY-NOTFOUND
-- Checking for [blas]
--   Library blas: BLAS_blas_LIBRARY-NOTFOUND
-- Cannot find a library with BLAS API. Not using BLAS.
-- Checking for [mkl_intel_lp64 - mkl_intel_thread - mkl_core - libiomp5md - pthread]
--   Library mkl_intel_lp64: not found
-- Checking for [mkl_intel - mkl_intel_thread - mkl_core - libiomp5md - pthread]
--   Library mkl_intel: not found
-- Checking for [mkl_intel_lp64 - mkl_intel_thread - mkl_core - pthread]
--   Library mkl_intel_lp64: not found
-- Checking for [mkl_intel - mkl_intel_thread - mkl_core - pthread]
--   Library mkl_intel: not found
-- Checking for [mkl_intel_lp64 - mkl_sequential - mkl_core]
--   Library mkl_intel_lp64: not found
-- Checking for [mkl_intel - mkl_sequential - mkl_core]
--   Library mkl_intel: not found
-- Checking for [mkl_intel_lp64 - mkl_sequential - mkl_core]
--   Library mkl_intel_lp64: not found
-- Checking for [mkl_intel - mkl_sequential - mkl_core]
--   Library mkl_intel: not found
-- Checking for [mkl_intel_lp64 - mkl_intel_thread - mkl_core - libiomp5md - pthread]
--   Library mkl_intel_lp64: not found
-- Checking for [mkl_intel - mkl_intel_thread - mkl_core - libiomp5md - pthread]
--   Library mkl_intel: not found
-- Checking for [mkl_intel_lp64 - mkl_intel_thread - mkl_core - pthread]
--   Library mkl_intel_lp64: not found
-- Checking for [mkl_intel - mkl_intel_thread - mkl_core - pthread]
--   Library mkl_intel: not found
-- Checking for [mkl - guide - pthread - m]
--   Library mkl: not found
-- MKL library not found
-- Checking for [openblas]
--   Library openblas: BLAS_openblas_LIBRARY-NOTFOUND
-- Checking for [openblas - pthread]
--   Library openblas: BLAS_openblas_LIBRARY-NOTFOUND
-- Checking for [libopenblas]
--   Library libopenblas: BLAS_libopenblas_LIBRARY-NOTFOUND
-- Checking for [goto2 - gfortran]
--   Library goto2: BLAS_goto2_LIBRARY-NOTFOUND
-- Checking for [goto2 - gfortran - pthread]
--   Library goto2: BLAS_goto2_LIBRARY-NOTFOUND
-- Checking for [acml - gfortran]
--   Library acml: BLAS_acml_LIBRARY-NOTFOUND
-- Checking for [Accelerate]
--   Library Accelerate: BLAS_Accelerate_LIBRARY-NOTFOUND
-- Checking for [vecLib]
--   Library vecLib: BLAS_vecLib_LIBRARY-NOTFOUND
-- Checking for [ptf77blas - atlas - gfortran]
--   Library ptf77blas: BLAS_ptf77blas_LIBRARY-NOTFOUND
-- Checking for [blas]
--   Library blas: BLAS_blas_LIBRARY-NOTFOUND
-- Cannot find a library with BLAS API. Not using BLAS.
-- LAPACK requires BLAS
-- Cannot find a library with LAPACK API. Not using LAPACK.
-- Performing Test C_HAS_THREAD
-- Performing Test C_HAS_THREAD - Success
CMake Deprecation Warning at lib/luaT/CMakeLists.txt:3 (CMAKE_POLICY):
  The OLD behavior for policy CMP0026 will be removed from a future version
  of CMake.

  The cmake-policies(7) manual explains that the OLD behaviors of all
  policies are deprecated and that a policy should be set to OLD only under
  specific short-term circumstances.  Projects should be ported to the NEW
  behavior and not rely on setting a policy to OLD.


-- Configuring done
-- Generating done
-- Build files have been written to: D:/Users/docte/AppData/Local/Temp/luarocks_torch-scm-1-1820/torch7/build

Microsoft (R) Program Maintenance Utility Version 12.00.21005.1
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.

Scanning dependencies of target TH
[  2%] Building C object lib/TH/CMakeFiles/TH.dir/THGeneral.c.obj
THGeneral.c
[  5%] Building C object lib/TH/CMakeFiles/TH.dir/THHalf.c.obj
THHalf.c
[  7%] Building C object lib/TH/CMakeFiles/TH.dir/THAllocator.c.obj
THAllocator.c
[ 10%] Building C object lib/TH/CMakeFiles/TH.dir/THSize.c.obj
THSize.c
[ 12%] Building C object lib/TH/CMakeFiles/TH.dir/THStorage.c.obj
THStorage.c
D:\Users\docte\AppData\Local\Temp\luarocks_torch-scm-1-1820\torch7\lib\TH\THStorage.c(18) : warning C4244: 'function' : conversion from 'const ptrdiff_t' to 'const long', possible loss of data

Now skipping some compiler warnings ...

d:\users\docte\appdata\local\temp\luarocks_torch-scm-1-1820\torch7\lib\th\generic/simd/simd.h(100) : error C2054: expected '(' to follow 'inline'
d:\users\docte\appdata\local\temp\luarocks_torch-scm-1-1820\torch7\lib\th\generic/simd/simd.h(101) : error C2085: 'cpuid' : not in formal parameter list
d:\users\docte\appdata\local\temp\luarocks_torch-scm-1-1820\torch7\lib\th\generic/simd/simd.h(101) : error C2143: syntax error : missing ';' before '{'
d:\users\docte\appdata\local\temp\luarocks_torch-scm-1-1820\torch7\lib\th\generic/simd/simd.h(123) : error C2054: expected '(' to follow 'inline'
d:\users\docte\appdata\local\temp\luarocks_torch-scm-1-1820\torch7\lib\th\generic/simd/simd.h(124) : error C2085: 'detectHostSIMDExtensions' : not in formal parameter list
d:\users\docte\appdata\local\temp\luarocks_torch-scm-1-1820\torch7\lib\th\generic/simd/simd.h(124) : error C2143: syntax error : missing ';' before '{'
d:\users\docte\appdata\local\temp\luarocks_torch-scm-1-1820\torch7\lib\th\THMath.h(4) : error C2054: expected '(' to follow 'inline'
d:\users\docte\appdata\local\temp\luarocks_torch-scm-1-1820\torch7\lib\th\THMath.h(4) : error C2085: 'TH_sigmoid' : not in formal parameter list
d:\users\docte\appdata\local\temp\luarocks_torch-scm-1-1820\torch7\lib\th\THMath.h(4) : error C2143: syntax error : missing ';' before '{'
d:\users\docte\appdata\local\temp\luarocks_torch-scm-1-1820\torch7\lib\th\THMath.h(8) : error C2054: expected '(' to follow 'inline'
d:\users\docte\appdata\local\temp\luarocks_torch-scm-1-1820\torch7\lib\th\THMath.h(8) : error C2085: 'TH_frac' : not in formal parameter list
d:\users\docte\appdata\local\temp\luarocks_torch-scm-1-1820\torch7\lib\th\THMath.h(8) : error C2143: syntax error : missing ';' before '{'
d:\users\docte\appdata\local\temp\luarocks_torch-scm-1-1820\torch7\lib\th\THMath.h(12) : error C2054: expected '(' to follow 'inline'
d:\users\docte\appdata\local\temp\luarocks_torch-scm-1-1820\torch7\lib\th\THMath.h(12) : error C2085: 'TH_rsqrt' : not in formal parameter list
d:\users\docte\appdata\local\temp\luarocks_torch-scm-1-1820\torch7\lib\th\THMath.h(12) : error C2143: syntax error : missing ';' before '{'
d:\users\docte\appdata\local\temp\luarocks_torch-scm-1-1820\torch7\lib\th\THMath.h(16) : error C2054: expected '(' to follow 'inline'
d:\users\docte\appdata\local\temp\luarocks_torch-scm-1-1820\torch7\lib\th\THMath.h(16) : error C2085: 'TH_lerp' : not in formal parameter list
d:\users\docte\appdata\local\temp\luarocks_torch-scm-1-1820\torch7\lib\th\THMath.h(16) : error C2143: syntax error : missing ';' before '{'
d:\users\docte\appdata\local\temp\luarocks_torch-scm-1-1820\torch7\lib\th\THMath.h(20) : error C2054: expected '(' to follow 'inline'
d:\users\docte\appdata\local\temp\luarocks_torch-scm-1-1820\torch7\lib\th\THMath.h(20) : error C2085: 'TH_sigmoidf' : not in formal parameter list
d:\users\docte\appdata\local\temp\luarocks_torch-scm-1-1820\torch7\lib\th\THMath.h(20) : error C2143: syntax error : missing ';' before '{'
d:\users\docte\appdata\local\temp\luarocks_torch-scm-1-1820\torch7\lib\th\THMath.h(24) : error C2054: expected '(' to follow 'inline'
d:\users\docte\appdata\local\temp\luarocks_torch-scm-1-1820\torch7\lib\th\THMath.h(24) : error C2085: 'TH_fracf' : not in formal parameter list
d:\users\docte\appdata\local\temp\luarocks_torch-scm-1-1820\torch7\lib\th\THMath.h(24) : error C2143: syntax error : missing ';' before '{'
d:\users\docte\appdata\local\temp\luarocks_torch-scm-1-1820\torch7\lib\th\THMath.h(28) : error C2054: expected '(' to follow 'inline'
d:\users\docte\appdata\local\temp\luarocks_torch-scm-1-1820\torch7\lib\th\THMath.h(28) : error C2085: 'TH_rsqrtf' : not in formal parameter list
d:\users\docte\appdata\local\temp\luarocks_torch-scm-1-1820\torch7\lib\th\THMath.h(28) : error C2143: syntax error : missing ';' before '{'
d:\users\docte\appdata\local\temp\luarocks_torch-scm-1-1820\torch7\lib\th\THMath.h(32) : error C2054: expected '(' to follow 'inline'
d:\users\docte\appdata\local\temp\luarocks_torch-scm-1-1820\torch7\lib\th\THMath.h(32) : error C2085: 'TH_lerpf' : not in formal parameter list
d:\users\docte\appdata\local\temp\luarocks_torch-scm-1-1820\torch7\lib\th\THMath.h(32) : error C2143: syntax error : missing ';' before '{'

skipping some warnings ...


NMAKE : fatal error U1077: '"D:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\VC\bin\amd64\cl.exe"' : return code '0x2'
Stop.
NMAKE : fatal error U1077: '"D:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\VC\BIN\amd64\nmake.exe"' : return code '0x2'
Stop.
NMAKE : fatal error U1077: '"D:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\VC\BIN\amd64\nmake.exe"' : return code '0x2'
Stop.

Error: Build error: Failed building.

D:\luainstall-64\build>
```

I know Torch7 is not officially supported on Windows yet, but it would be a great help for the community if we had a successful solution. I am definitely available this full week to succeed, but I feel I need a kick or two with the help of some Torch7 dependencies expert that can help me focusing on what is mandatory I do at this stage.

If we make it work under Windows 10, either with MSVC or MinGW it will be a success for the Lua Windows Community!!!

Comment: 2021 update: download latest version of wget on windows 10 if it fails to fetch manifest from GitHub

Comment: Thanks for the cue Mauricio! Will do when I update. Cheers!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK Microsoft Windows 10 Users. I solved this amazing installation/configuration/re-compilation puzzle using VS2013 x64 (one could most likely succeed as well using VS2017 and maybe even VS2019). The solution is based on Siavash Gorji 's instructions - see: https://libraries.io/github/SiavashGorji/LuaJIT-Luarocks-Torch7 that I followed step by step while keeping an exact and detailed log of everything I had to do.

Today, I must keep going at installing the optional, but important for execution speed, Installing (recompiling) the NVIDIA CUDA software layers (cutorch, cunn, cunnx and cudnn Modules). And I will post in here, these additional steps later today.

-1) Today, I did installed the full Intel MKL Library for my VS2013 and VS2017 installs

0) Now, after a reboot, this is an attempt to successfully install LuaJIT-Luarocks-Torch7 using VS2013 x64 Native Tools Command Prompt

0.5) To have the Intel MKL Library detected this time around, set environment variables for this VS2013 x64 Native Tools Command Prompt
as specified by https://software.intel.com/en-us/mkl-windows-developer-guide-setting-environment-variables
and Intel MKL Library installation notes at https://software.intel.com/en-us/mkl/choose-download/windows

```
cd "D:\Program Files (x86)\IntelSWTools\compilers_and_libraries_2019\windows\mkl\bin"
d:
mklvars.bat intel64
```

1) Then, we re-build LuaJIT-Luarocks (hoping this time it sees the Intel MKL Library):

```
cd D:\luainstall-64\build
d:
cmake .. -G "NMake Makefiles" -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=%LuaJIT-Luarocks-Torch7_ROOT%\install
nmake
cmake .. -G "NMake Makefiles" -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=%LuaJIT-Luarocks-Torch7_ROOT%\install -P cmake_install.cmake
```

2) the rocks cwrap and paths are installed, so keep attempting to install luarocks install torch

```
luarocks list

luarocks install torch
```

but, "luarocks install torch" returns error, starting with "inline" not being defined,
inline is a c99 keyword and c99 is not yet (fully) supported with MSVC (ref. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z8y1yy88.aspx).

we can define:

```
-Dinline=__inline
```

to do so:

```
cd D:\luainstall-64\install\luarocks
d:
luarocks download torch

edit rockspec file D:\luainstall-64\install\luarocks\torch-scm-1.rockspec
add -Dinline=__inline (let's say after "cmake -E make_directory build && cd build && cmake .. " and before "-DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release -DLUA=$(LUA) -DLUALIB=$(LUALIB) -DLUA_BINDIR="$(LUA_BINDIR)" -DLUA_INCDIR="$(LUA_INCDIR)" -DLUA_LIBDIR="$(LUA_LIBDIR)" -DLUADIR="$(LUADIR)" -DLIBDIR="$(LIBDIR)" -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX="$(PREFIX)" && $(MAKE)")
luarocks unpack torch-scm-1.rockspec
cd torch-scm-1\torch7
edit CMakeLists.txt
```

so the section "Flags when using MSVC" looks like this:

```
# Flags
# When using MSVC
IF(MSVC)
  # we want to respect the standard, and we are bored of those **** .
  ADD_DEFINITIONS(-D_CRT_SECURE_NO_DEPRECATE=1)
  # spi, begin
  # "luarocks install torch" returns error, starting with "inline" not being defined,
  # inline is a c99 keyword and c99 is not yet (fully) supported with MSVC (ref. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z8y1yy88.aspx).
  ADD_DEFINITIONS(-Dinline=__inline)
  SET(CMAKE_EXE_LINKER_FLAGS "${CMAKE_EXE_LINKER_FLAGS} /FORCE")
  SET(CMAKE_SHARED_LINKER_FLAGS "${CMAKE_SHARED_LINKER_FLAGS} /FORCE")
  # spi, end
ENDIF(MSVC)
```

now, ready to build using:

```
luarocks make ..\..\torch-scm-1.rockspec
```

And "luarocks torch install" works, at last!!!

To test the torch installation, we can create and display a 2x3x4 randomly initialized tensor on a regular Command Prompt by:

```
luajit
require "torch"
print(torch.Tensor(2,3,4))
```

It works!!!

Finnaly, set Torch_DIR as an Environment Variable to the LuaJIT-Luarocks-Torch7_ROOT%\share\cmake\torch directory:

```
setx Torch_DIR %LuaJIT-Luarocks-Torch7_ROOT%\share\cmake\torch
(for me, I edit the system environment variables from the controlpanel, adding Torch_DIR D:\luainstall-64\share\cmake\torch)
```

So, I must therefore close the VS2013 x64 Native Tools Command Prompt
and re-open a new VS2013 x64 Native Tools Command Prompt again

```
cd "D:\Program Files (x86)\IntelSWTools\compilers_and_libraries_2019\windows\mkl\bin"
d:
mklvars.bat intel64
```

Now, Installing Torch Modules:

When you install torch on Unix environments, it will automatically installs "lots of nice goodies". In the following section, we try to install them (i.e. most of them) one by one using luarocks installer. Try to install these in the same order presented here. To install some of the lua/torch modules that contain C code on Windows, we need to make some changes to them (since we are basically porting them from Linux). You can find all such editted modules inside the extra folder in "%LuaJIT-Luarocks-Torch7_ROOT%. To install these, we will use luarocks local installation capabality (i.e. using "luarocks make" instead of "luarocks install"). As you can see below, all we need to do is to cd the NTCP to the main directory of each module, and run "luarocks make path-to-module-rockspec-file".

```
luarocks install luafilesystem
luarocks install penlight

cd %LuaJIT-Luarocks-Torch7_ROOT%\extra\lua-cjson
(for me, cd D:\luainstall-64\extra\lua-cjson)
luarocks make lua-cjson-2.1devel-1.rockspec

cd %LuaJIT-Luarocks-Torch7_ROOT%\extra\luaffifb
(for me, cd D:\luainstall-64\extra\luaffifb)
luarocks make luaffi-scm-1.rockspec

luarocks install sundown
luarocks install dok

cd %LuaJIT-Luarocks-Torch7_ROOT%\extra\sys
(for me, cd D:\luainstall-64\extra\sys)
luarocks make sys-1.1-0.rockspec

luarocks install xlua
```

but "luarocks install nn" does not go through, need to luarocks download, luarocks unpack and luarocks make:

```
cd D:\luainstall-64\install\luarocks
d:
luarocks download nn
edit rockspec file D:\luainstall-64\install\luarocks\nn-scm-1.rockspec
add -Dinline=__inline
luarocks unpack nn-scm-1.rockspec
cd nn-scm-1\nn
edit CMakeLists.txt
```

so the section "Flags when using MSVC" looks like this:

```
# Flags
# When using MSVC
IF(MSVC)
  # we want to respect the standard, and we are bored of those **** .
  ADD_DEFINITIONS(-D_CRT_SECURE_NO_DEPRECATE=1)
  # spi, begin
  # "luarocks install nn" returns error, starting with "inline" not being defined,
  # inline is a c99 keyword and c99 is not yet (fully) supported with MSVC (ref. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z8y1yy88.aspx).
  ADD_DEFINITIONS(-Dinline=__inline)
  SET(CMAKE_EXE_LINKER_FLAGS "${CMAKE_EXE_LINKER_FLAGS} /FORCE")
  SET(CMAKE_SHARED_LINKER_FLAGS "${CMAKE_SHARED_LINKER_FLAGS} /FORCE")
  # spi, end
ENDIF(MSVC)
```

now, ready to build using:

```
rename D:\luainstall-64\install\luarocks\nn nn-backup
luarocks make ..\..\nn-scm-1.rockspec
```

failing to build nn, because of

```
d:\luainstall-64\install\luarocks\nn-scm-1\nn\lib\thnn\generic/FeatureLPPooling.c(214) : error C2143: syntax error : missing ';' before 'type'
unsigned type not supported in openmp 2.0 (which is the version msvc 2013 supports), 
so, for 2 blocks of code in FeatureLPPooling.c, I replaced the type size_t by long (within the 2 pragma omp parallel for blocks of code)
also, not declaring any counter variables within for statement (within the pragma omp parallel for here below, 
moving counter variables declaration before each for loop
```

retrying to to build nn

```
cd D:\luainstall-64\install\luarocks\nn-scm-1\nn
d:
luarocks make ..\..\nn-scm-1.rockspec
```

and the build works!!!

```
luarocks install graph
luarocks install nngraph
```

but "luarocks install image" does not go through
-- Could NOT find JPEG (missing: JPEG_LIBRARY JPEG_INCLUDE_DIR)
-- Could NOT find ZLIB (missing: ZLIB_LIBRARY ZLIB_INCLUDE_DIR)
-- Could NOT find PNG (missing: PNG_LIBRARY PNG_PNG_INCLUDE_DIR)
so, see https://devblogs.microsoft.com/cppblog/vcpkg-a-tool-to-acquire-and-build-c-open-source-libraries-on-windows/

```
Clone from GitHub: git clone https://github.com/Microsoft/vcpkg
Run the bootstrap script in the vcpkg folder:
D:\vcpkg> .\bootstrap-vcpkg.bat
d:\vcpkg>vcpkg integrate install
```

Applied user-wide integration for this vcpkg root.

```
d:\vcpkg>vcpkg install openjpeg:x64-windows
d:\vcpkg>vcpkg install zlib:x64-windows
```

zlib install did not succeed

```
vcpkg update
```

retry zlib install

```
d:\vcpkg>vcpkg install zlib:x64-windows
```

zlib install succeeded

```
d:\vcpkg>vcpkg install libpng:x64-windows
```

libpng install did not succeed
retry

```
d:\vcpkg>vcpkg install libpng:x64-windows
```

libpng install succeeded

now, retry installing "luarocks install image"

```
luarocks install image
```

it does not go through
-- Could NOT find JPEG (missing: JPEG_LIBRARY JPEG_INCLUDE_DIR)
-- Could NOT find ZLIB (missing: ZLIB_LIBRARY ZLIB_INCLUDE_DIR)
-- Could NOT find PNG (missing: PNG_LIBRARY PNG_PNG_INCLUDE_DIR)
set the 6 following environment variables:

```
JPEG_LIBRARY D:\vcpkg\packages\openjpeg_x64-windows\lib
JPEG_INCLUDE_DIR D:\vcpkg\packages\openjpeg_x64-windows\include
ZLIB_LIBRARY D:\vcpkg\packages\zlib_x64-windows\lib
ZLIB_INCLUDE_DIR D:\vcpkg\packages\zlib_x64-windows\include
PNG_LIBRARY D:\vcpkg\packages\libpng_x64-windows\lib
PNG_PNG_INCLUDE_DIR D:\vcpkg\packages\libpng_x64-windows\include
```

(for me, I edit the system environment variables from the controlpanel)
So, I must therefore close the VS2013 x64 Native Tools Command Prompt
and re-open a new VS2013 x64 Native Tools Command Prompt again

```
cd "D:\Program Files (x86)\IntelSWTools\compilers_and_libraries_2019\windows\mkl\bin"
d:
mklvars.bat intel64
cd D:\luainstall-64\install\luarocks
d:
```

now, retry installing "luarocks install image"

```
luarocks install image
```

(2019july25, 12h56am) "luarocks install image" still not seeing jpeg, zlib and png libraries

so, "luarocks install image" does not go through, need to luarocks download, luarocks unpack and luarocks make:

```
cd D:\luainstall-64\install\luarocks
d:
luarocks download image
edit rockspec file D:\luainstall-64\install\luarocks\image-1.1.alpha-0.rockspec
```

add this define to cmake command:

```
"-DCMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE=d:/vcpkg/scripts/buildsystems/vcpkg.cmake"
i.e. cmake -DCMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE=d:/vcpkg/scripts/buildsystems/vcpkg.cmake
add also -Dinline=__inline to this cmake command
also add -DJPEG_LIBRARY=D:/vcpkg/packages/openjpeg_x64-windows/lib
along with -DJPEG_INCLUDE_DIR=D:/vcpkg/packages/openjpeg_x64-windows/include
luarocks unpack image-1.1.alpha-0.rockspec
cd image-1.1.alpha-0/image
edit CMakeLists.txt
```

at the top, after the FIND_PACKAGE statements, add this line

```
ADD_DEFINITIONS(-Dinline=__inline)
```

now, ready to build using:

```
rename D:\luainstall-64\install\luarocks\image image-backup
luarocks make ..\..\image-1.1.alpha-0.rockspec
```

this time, build success, but it still did not find the jpeg library
so, at the top, after the FIND_PACKAGE statements and the previous

```
ADD_DEFINITIONS(-Dinline=__inline) statement ...
```

add this line

```
ADD_DEFINITIONS(-DJPEG_LIBRARY="D:/vcpkg/packages/openjpeg_x64-windows/lib")
```

add this line

```
ADD_DEFINITIONS(-DJPEG_INCLUDE_DIR="D:/vcpkg/packages/openjpeg_x64-windows/include")
```

now, ready to build again using:

```
luarocks make ..\..\image-1.1.alpha-0.rockspec
```

ok, this time the code is looking for the header jpeglib.h which is not in openjpeg library
at the time of this document writing, microsoft vcpkg can't install libjpeg nor will it successfully install libjpeg-turbo
so, I directly download libjpeg-turbo from https://sourceforge.net/projects/libjpeg-turbo/files/2.0.0/libjpeg-turbo-2.0.0-vc64.exe/download
and install it and revise (edit again) my libjpeg related environment variables (using controlpanel environment variable editor)

```
JPEG_LIBRARY D:\libjpeg-turbo64\lib
JPEG_INCLUDE_DIR D:\libjpeg-turbo64\include
```

once again, let's edit rockspec file

```
edit D:\luainstall-64\install\luarocks\image-1.1.alpha-0.rockspec
```

and revise (change) the libjpeg related defines proving the new path to libjpeg-turbo's folders with forward slashes for safety

```
-DJPEG_LIBRARY=D:/libjpeg-turbo64/lib/jpeg.lib 
-DJPEG_LIBRARY2=D:/libjpeg-turbo64/lib/turbojpeg.lib 
-DJPEG_INCLUDE_DIR=D:/libjpeg-turbo64/include
```

now, let's do again

```
cd D:\luainstall-64\install\luarocks
d:
luarocks unpack image-1.1.alpha-0.rockspec
cd image-1.1.alpha-0/image
edit CMakeLists.txt
```

at the top, after the FIND_PACKAGE statements, add this line

```
ADD_DEFINITIONS(-Dinline=__inline)
```

add this line

```
ADD_DEFINITIONS(-DJPEG_LIBRARY="D:/libjpeg-turbo64/lib/jpeg.lib")
```

add this line

```
ADD_DEFINITIONS(-DJPEG_LIBRARY2="D:/libjpeg-turbo64/lib/turbojpeg.lib")
```

add this line

```
ADD_DEFINITIONS(-DJPEG_INCLUDE_DIR="D:/libjpeg-turbo64/include")
```

and in the "if (JPEG_FOUND)" block, replace the 2 lines here below

replace

```
SET(CMAKE_REQUIRED_LIBRARIES "${JPEG_LIBRARY}")
```

with

```
SET(CMAKE_REQUIRED_LIBRARIES "${JPEG_LIBRARY} ${JPEG_LIBRARY2}")
```

and replace

```
TARGET_LINK_LIBRARIES(jpeg luaT TH ${JPEG_LIBRARIES})
```

with

```
TARGET_LINK_LIBRARIES(jpeg luaT TH ${JPEG_LIBRARIES} ${JPEG_LIBRARY} ${JPEG_LIBRARY2})
```

now, ready to build again using:

```
luarocks make ..\..\image-1.1.alpha-0.rockspec

cd D:\luainstall-64\install\luarocks
d:
luarocks install optim
luarocks install gnuplot
luarocks install env

cd %LuaJIT-Luarocks-Torch7_ROOT%\extra\nnx
luarocks make nnx-0.1-1.rockspec

luarocks install graphicsmagick
luarocks install argcheck
luarocks install fftw3

cd %LuaJIT-Luarocks-Torch7_ROOT%\extra\torch-signal
luarocks make ./rocks/signal-scm-1.rockspec



luarocks install class
luarocks install rational
luarocks install cairo

cd %LuaJIT-Luarocks-Torch7_ROOT%\extra\luasocket
luarocks make ./rockspec/luasocket-3.0rc2-1.rockspec
```

OK, success so far

First part of the complete solution found!

If some of you want to reproduce this, see the reference section here below to see how I got to today's point.

Cheers,

Steph

for reference: (the day before, I started doing these steps)

1) Installation (windows 64 bit)

I choose to install in:

```
D:\luainstall-64
```

Set environment variables:

```
LuaJIT-Luarocks-Torch7_ROOT D:\luainstall-64
```

On Windows - use command prompt with appropritate environment (I used VS2013 x64 Native Tools Command Prompt)

```
cd %LuaJIT-Luarocks-Torch7_ROOT%\..
git clone https://github.com/SiavashGorji/LuaJIT-Luarocks-Torch7.git
cd %LuaJIT-Luarocks-Torch7_ROOT%
mkdir build
cd build

cmake .. -G "NMake Makefiles" -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=%LuaJIT-Luarocks-Torch7_ROOT%\install
nmake
cmake .. -G "NMake Makefiles" -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=%LuaJIT-Luarocks-Torch7_ROOT%\install -P cmake_install.cmake


setx path "%LuaJIT-Luarocks-Torch7_ROOT%\install;%path%"
D:\luainstall-64\install

setx LUA_PATH .\?.lua;C:\Programs\LuaJIT-Luarocks-Torch7\install\lua\?.lua;C:\Programs\LuaJIT-Luarocks-Torch7\install\lua\?\init.lua;
set LUA_PATH .\?.lua;D:\luainstall-64\install\lua\?.lua;D:\luainstall-64\install\lua\?\init.lua;

setx LUA_CPATH .\?.dll;C:\Programs\LuaJIT-Luarocks-Torch7\install\?.dll;C:\Programs\LuaJIT-Luarocks-Torch7\install\loadall.dll
set LUA_CPATH .\?.dll;D:\luainstall-64\install\?.dll;D:\luainstall-64\install\loadall.dll

setx LUA_DEV %LuaJIT-Luarocks-Torch7_ROOT%\install
```

IMPORTANT NOTE:
Note that in the installation directory, there is a cmake.cmd which automatically appends any cmake commands (which are called by luarocks) with the -G "NMake Makefiles" flag. In order for this to work, you should make sure that the installation directory precedes cmake installation directory.
So, I did put D:\luainstall-64\install first in the system path (way before the path for cmake).

2) Torch7 (windows 64 bit)

On Windows - use command prompt with appropriate environment (I used VS2013 x64 Native Tools Command Prompt)

```
luarocks install cwrap

luarocks install paths

luarocks install torch
```

but got an error at some point during luarocks install torch:

```
[ 61%] Generating TensorMath.c
NMAKE : fatal error U1077: 'D:\luainstall-64\install\luajit.EXE' : return code '0xc0000005'
Stop.
NMAKE : fatal error U1077: '"D:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.16.27023\bin\HostX64\x64\nmake.exe"' : return code '0x2'
Stop.
NMAKE : fatal error U1077: '"D:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.16.27023\bin\HostX64\x64\nmake.exe"' : return code '0x2'
Stop.

Error: Build error: Failed building.
```